# How to get X and Y position in jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I am familiar with getting X and Y coordinates with mouse position however, I am animating using CSS transform  *"translate"*  and  *"rotate"*  functions. Is it possible to get X and Y positions of animating image when you don't use mouse events ? The image is moving down and rotating at the same time I would like to see its X and Y position since I want to add fadeout() function at the specific coordinate. X position is zero here but I will be changing it too. Here is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var logoVar = $('#logo');
    var rotateVar =0;

    $({translateVar: 0, rotateVar: 0}).animate( 
    {
        translateVar: 200,
        rotateVar: 360 
    },
    { // animate method options below 
        duration: 5000,  // 5 seconds for the entire animation
        step: function(now, abc){  

            if(abc.prop == 'translateVar')
                translateVar = now;
            else if(abc.prop =='rotateVar')
                rotateVar =now; 

            logoVar.css('transform', 'translate(0px, ' + now + 'px) rotate(' + rotateVar + 'deg)' );        
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `offset()`, such that for Y you have:

```
logoVar.offset().top
```

Then for X you use:

```
logoVar.offset().left
```

And because everyone loves API documentation as a source: http://api.jquery.com/offset/